# Is possible to fetch fingerprint data in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using a fingerprint scanner plugin in my project. I can use my mobile device fingerprint authenticate data only. I need access app inside fingerprint authenticate but I don't know knowledge in fingerprint data so how to get authenticate data. Is possible to fetch data in react native.

Plugin used:

> react-native-fingerprint-scanner

Comment: You can store whatever you want in redux. It's just an object.

Comment: @kai how to get fingerprint data

Comment: What sort of data do you need, and why? The fingerprint scanner is for authenticating the user, and returns either true or false.

Comment: With iOS you’ll not be able to store the actual finger print as that is abstracted away from you, and there is no way to access it.

Comment: @Kai I want to access secure screen in my application. so create fingerprint authentication . so how to get fingerprint data.

Comment: The documentation for that library is pretty simple, you call a method and it returns a boolean, which you can then use to decide whether or not to allow the user to navigate

Comment: @kai thank you, but Is possible or not

Comment: Authenticating a user with their fingerprint? yes. Getting the underlying numeric output for the fingerprint? no, that would be a security issue, and the operating system does not allow it